# Aria-live content read twice by Mac - Chrome - VoiceOver

Tags: javascript, html, accessibility, wcag2.0

Aria-live content read twice by Mac - Chrome - VoiceOver, when the content is in the iframe. Below links are the example by "developer mozilla". I want to know whether this is an issue or not, If so, is there any solution to fix this?

Links

1. [Aria-live in iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Live_Regions) In this link aria-live content reads twice.
2. [Aria-live not in iframe](https://mdn.mozillademos.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Live_Regions$samples/Dropdown_box_updates_useful_onscreen_information?revision=1567677) In this link aria-live reads content only once.

Comment: I'm also experiencing this issue. I didn't realize it was just in iFrame's though. Thank you for pointing that out. I'm testing in Storybook, which loads in an iFrame, so that would make sense. To add on to this, I'm only experiencing this issue when the politeness setting is "polite". It doesn't seem to effect "assertive" announcements. Also, I'm seeing this in Safari and Firefox on my Mac as well.

Answer (score 10):

It's a known issue and a bug in VoiceOver, with apparently no known solution.

Read:  [VoiceOver duplicates alerts in iframes](https://github.com/phetsims/a11y-research/issues/132)

According to that page, a bug report has been sent to Apple

A Twitter User, [Ryan Seddon says](https://twitter.com/ryanseddon/status/1200270461696786433) that the bug only appear with `aria-live=polite` and not `assertive`

Comment: In my experience, `assertive` still reads twice, but it tends to be much more verbose on top of it.

Comment: Can confirm that both assertive and polite read it twice

Answer (score 0):

Can you try by giving some role to the element where you keep aria-live?

Ex:

```
<div aria-live="polite" role="text"> ..... </div>
```